# Conversion of string to upper case without inbuilt methods

Tags: python, function, case-conversion

I am trying to perform conversion from a lowercase to uppercase on a string without using any inbuilt functions (other than ord() and char()). Following the logic presented on a different thread here , I came up with this.

```
def uppercase(str_data):
   ord('str_data')
   str_data = str_data -32
   chr('str_data')
   return str_data
print(uppercase('abcd'))
```

However I am getting an error output: TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 8 found.What am I missing here?

Comment: We need to know more about the constraints. Can the input string only contain lower case alphabetic characters?

Comment: Also, "I am not getting any output" seems unlikely. The output should be `TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 4 found`.

Comment: Also how are `ord` and `chr` (which you misspelled) not inbuilt functions?

Comment: My apologies, I have rectified the misspelled chr. I am allowed to use chr() and ord() functions.

Comment: On the one hand, I understand the rationale of teachers restricting the use of various built-in functions and methods when they are trying to teach particular programming concepts. OTOH, the resulting code is often rather un-Pythonic: Python is famous for coming with "batteries included", and a Python course should teach you how to use those batteries, not forbid you from using them.

Comment: @PM2Ring I agree. I think this assignment would be improved by having a second part, to the tune of "and then verify that your solution produces the same output as the built-in str.upper() function, on the following three inputs..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to execute ord() for each character of your input string. instead of the input string:

```
def uppercase(str_data):
    return ''.join([chr(ord(char) - 32) for char in str_data if ord(char) >= 65])

print(uppercase('abcdé--#'))
>>> ABCDÉ
```

Without join:

```
def uppercase(str_data):
    result = ''
    for char in str_data:
        if ord(char) >= 65:
            result += chr(ord(char) - 32)
    return result
print(uppercase('abcdé--#λ'))
>>> ABCDÉΛ
```

Comment: Does not work for special characters like `;` or `/`

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can you suggest without the join function? I am not allowed to use it. Also, @Mr -Xcoder, I can pass of special characters such as ; or / as exceptions. Using only alphabets for my case. Simple words

Comment: Now it is better, it does not use `index()` as well and now that it meets the requirements it's a really good answer.

Answer (score 1):

The best way, in my opinion is using a helper string, representing the alphabet, if you do not want to use `chr()` and `ord()`:

```
def toUppercase(s):
    alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
    result = ''
    for x in s:
        if x not in alphabet or alphabet.index(x)>=26:
            result += x
        else:
            result += alphabet[alphabet.index(x)+26]
    return result
```

This also handles punctuation such as `;` or `.`.

---

### Update:

As per the OP's request, this is a version without `index()`:

```
def toUppercase(s):
    alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
    result = ''
    for x in s:
        for pos in range(52):
            if alphabet[pos] == x:
                i = pos
        if x not in alphabet or i>=26:
            result += x
        else:
            result += alphabet[i+26]
    return result

print(toUppercase('abcdj;shjgh'))
```

Comment: Kind Sir, Thanks for your response. However I am not allowed to use the join function. I am beginner in python still and dunno if the index is an inbuilt function or not. If yes, then again I cannot use it.

Comment: @phoenix_9 I will provide a version with no `join()` in a sec.

Comment: @phoenix_9 Done, check the updated code... There was actually no need for `join()`, silly me. My mistake.

Comment: I looked over [built-in functions in Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html), and there is no `index()` in that list.

Comment: The OP is probably not allowed to use `str` methods like `.index` if they aren't allowed to use other `str` methods like  `.upper` or `.join`.

Comment: Well, that's true. Trying to fix this without `index()` @PM2Ring

Comment: Thanks again. Yes, like @PM 2Ring mentioned. I was not sure about the index method. But your code works just fine. Thanks !

Comment: @phoenix_9 uploaded a version without `index()`,`chr()` or `ord()`, check it out!

Comment: @PM2Ring Fixed.

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a program to convert the string to uppercase without using inbuilt functions:

```
Str1=input("Enter the string to be converted uppercase: ")

for i in range (0,len(Str1)):

   x=ord(Str1[i])
   if x>=97 and x<=122:
       x=x-32
   y=chr(x)
   print(y,end="")
```

Answer (score 0):

ord()- Return the Unicode code point for a one-character string.

You have to send a one character string as an argument. Here, you are sending the string 'abcd' which has 4 characters which is causing the issue. Send each character separately to the function and thus do 4 calls to the function to get the result.

Comment: Terribly inefficient. You cannot do 100 calls if you have a 100-characters string.

Comment: Agreed. I was just giving the solution for this case.

Answer (score 0):

The below-simplified code help to **convert Lower-case alphabets to Upper-case** alphabets using a simple calculation

code :

```
def toUppercase(string):
    convertedCharacter = ''
    for i in string: 
         convertCharacter += chr( ( (ord(i)) -32) ) 
    return convertCharacter
```

Answer (score 0):

```
char=input("Enter lowercase word :")
for letter in char:
    s=ord(letter)
    if s>=97 and s<=122:
        print(chr(s-32),end=" ")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def uppercase(str_data):
   ord('str_data')
   str_data = str_data -32
   chr('str_data')
   return str_data
print(uppercase('abcd'))
```

in this code ord takes single character as an argument but you have given more than one that's why it's showing an error. Take single character at a time convert it to upper case and make a single string like below.

```
def convert_to_lower(string):
    new="" 
    for i in string:
       j=ord(i)-32  #we are taking the ascii value because the length of lower 
             #case to uppercase is 32 so we are subtracting 32

       if 97<=ord(i)<=122 :  #here we are checking whether the charecter is lower
                      # case or not if lowercase then only we are converting into
                      #uppercase
           new=new+chr(j)
       else:  #if the character is not the lowercase alplhaber we are taking as it is
           new=new+i
    print(new)

convert_to_lower("hello world")
```